# Lotus Notes:Web page refresh restriction on attachment upload

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a situation, in which I want to restrict my web page to refresh after I attach a document.
The secnerio is there is some hide when condition written on OnLoad of the Form using javascript, and as soon as the form loads the hide when is active but below that we have more hide when on the basis of selection of a drop down, that is also working, but if I attach a document the web page refreshes and the onload triggers, which further enables the first hide-whne and then again I have to select from drop-down to enable the next hide-when.

Please help if we can restrict web-page refresh after attachment upload.

Comment: Please add some or your code snippet to your question.

Comment: How are you attaching the file? Through a rich text upload control? Is this a Notes Form in edit mode? Please provide some additional detail.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem might be more that you have to re-select the drop-down to get the hide-when on that to work after a refresh ? That is, the value is already selected, so there's no change, so the hide-when isn't triggered ? 
If so, you probably need to package up the drop-down's hide-when code into a function (if it isn't aleready) and always call that during onload so that if the page refreshes, all hide-when is honoured.

That's assuming the hide-when resulting form the drop-down change is also in Javascript. If it isn't and you have "Refresh fields on keyword change" ticked in the Notes Designer field's properties, then that's what's causing the second refresh, and your best best would be to un-tick that peoperty and simulate the resulting hide-when using javascript, with an onchange event on the drop-down.